# Query builder with AND and OR

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I work in *Symfony 3.4 flex*, I need to do one querybuilder like this :

All media with "*published*" at True AND media is *TYPE OF* :`type AND ((condition 1) OR (condition 2) OR (condition 3))` with a symfony doctrine query builder. These 2 conditions are already true (published and instance of :instance):

```
 $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->chere('m.published = :published')
        ->andWhere('m INSTANCE OF :instance');

/* 
WHERE m.published = true AND m INSTANCE OF :instance

AND (
    //    ('m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate >= :today')
    // OR ('m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate >= :today')
    // OR ('m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate IS NULL')
    // OR ('m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate IS NULL')
*/
```

When I try something like :

```
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->lte('m.startDate', ':today'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->gte('m.endDate', ':today'))
   );
```

But it doesn't work it return something like :

```
WHERE (
    (m.published = 1 AND m.type IN (:type)) // I already needed this in all cond
    AND m.start_date <= :today AND m.end_date >= :today // cond 1
)

    OR (m.start_date IS NULL :today AND m.end_date IS NULL) // cond 2
    OR ... // cond 3
```

So my condition with `((m.published = 1 AND m.type IN (:type)))` need to be in all conditions not only the first

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->where("((m.published = true AND m INSTANCE OF :instance) AND
                      (
                          (m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate >= :today) OR
                          (m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate >= :today) OR
                          (m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate IS NULL) OR
                          (m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate IS NULL)
                      )
                 )"
               );
```

Answer (score 4):

For your own knowledge, with DQL, it would be like this:

```
//Important to have it initialized alone so you can use it for expressions
$qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('m');

$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->andX(
    "m.published=1",
    "m INSTANCE OF :instance",
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->andX("m.startDate <= :today", "m.endDate >= :today"),
        $qb->expr()->andX("m.startDate IS NULL", "m.endDate >= :today"),
        $qb->expr()->andX("m.startDate IS NULL", "m.endDate IS NULL"),
        $qb->expr()->andX("m.startDate <= :today", "m.endDate IS NULL")
    )
))
->setParameters(array(
    'instance'=>$instance,
    'today'=>$today,
))
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

It will give you the following DQL query:

```
SELECT m
FROM AppBundle\Entity\Media m
WHERE m.published=1
    AND m INSTANCE OF :instance
    AND ((m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate >= :today)
        OR (m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate >= :today)
        OR (m.startDate IS NULL AND m.endDate IS NULL)
        OR (m.startDate <= :today AND m.endDate IS NULL))
```

**Some tips:**

Never use `where()` or `orWhere`, its bound to give you problems someday
You can read more about it [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where)

Always use double quotes for your query.
Doctrine will only accept single quote for strings in query

Comment: Thank you for all precisions it s really interesting and usefull =)